# NodeJS: Unable to post Form data via Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

I am submitting form fields both via `request` and `Axios`. The request version works fine but not Axios one. My guess is that I am not submitting data properly. Sharing the both version

```
const data = {
        'CSRF': csrf,
        'anti-csrftoken-a2z': '',
        'offerListingID': offerListingID
}
```

**Request Version which works fine, returns 3021 redirect**

```
request({url:urlAddItem,headers:headers,method:'POST',gzip:true,form:data},(error:any,response:any,html:string) => {
                console.log(response.statusCode)
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    //
                }
            });
```

**Axios Version which does not work, returns 200**

```
const response = await axios({
                method: "post",
                url: urlAddItem,
                headers: headers,
                data:data
            });
            console.log(response.status )
```

I am unable to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first convert your object to form data. You can use this function to do that

```
function createFormData(obj, form, namespace) {
  const formData = form || new FormData();
  for (const property in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(property) || isUndefined(obj[property])) {
      continue;
    }
    const formKey = namespace ? `${namespace}[${property}]` : property;
    if (obj[property] instanceof Date) {
      formData.append(formKey, obj[property].toISOString());
    } else if (typeof obj[property] === 'object' && !(obj[property] instanceof File)) {
      createFormData(obj[property], formData, formKey);
    } else {
      formData.append(formKey, obj[property]);
    }
  }
  return formData;
}
```

Then do

```
await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: urlAddItem,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
    data: createFormData(data)
});
```